# Linux - Calculate session duration and add it to your prompt

Tags: linux, shell, session, command-line, command-prompt

Is there a way to calculate what is the session duration or the length of the session for the current user?

I know using `last` command we can get the login and idle times of the user but is there a direct command or any math that can be done to calculate from time now to time when the user had logged in.

Also how to add this session duration info in the prompt. I know using `export PS1` it can be achieved but what would be the parameter that will go in?

Any help is appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this in Bash is by adding this to your .bashrc:

```
PS1="\$SECONDS $PS1"
```

Assuming you aren't doing anything exotic with your PS1 already, like setting it dynamically with `PROMPT_COMMAND` or whatever. You need the backslash before `$SECONDS` to ensure it's evaluated every time. (You could also use single quotes, but it's probably unnecessary to evaluate `$PS1` every time too.)

This just gives you a bare number representing the number of seconds the session has existed. For fancier formatting, you'll have to expend some more effort. For example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='SESSIONTIME=$(printf "%02d:%02d:%02d" $(($SECONDS / 3600)) $(($SECONDS / 60 % 60)) $(($SECONDS % 60)))'
PS1="\$SESSIONTIME $PS1"
```

Other shells may have `SECONDS`, but they won't have `PROMPT_COMMAND`; in zsh, for example, you can accomplish the same thing by defining a `precmd` function. Read the documentation.

Comment: I have already edited my PS1 to have my `user@hostname[current date and time]: $` format. After the date and time I would like to add his extra piece of info about session duration.

Comment: I found out a command `uptime` which gives me an o/p like this `09:18:04 up 31 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.13, 0.98, 0.82` where 31 min is what I need. This is more simple, isnt it? Just that I'm not very good to every time pick that bit from uptime command and display it on my prompt. any ideas?

Comment: Uptime is how long the machine itself has been up, not your session duration.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the shell you use. In `bash`, the value of the `SECONDS` parameter is the number of seconds since the current shell was started.

Comment: Note this also works at least in `pdksh` and `zsh`, but not `csh`. It's obviously not universal, but it seems to be common...